# how to push code to two repositories but with some different content and gitignore files?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, repository, devops

### Context

I have code in a **private gitlab** repository which I want to have a `.env` file sent and a `Readme.md` with links referencing gitlab URL's.

### The problem

From time to time, I'll need to "deploy" this code to a **public github** repository. Here comes the *problem*: **I don't want to** have a second repository(the **github one**) on my machine that, when needed, **overwrite** all previous and *out-of-date* code; **Change the links** referencing gitlab code to github code and **also review if there's no sensitive info** such as a `.env`file being pushed to the **public github repo**

### What I would like

I'd like to push code to my **private gitlab** repo and *automatically push* this code to the **private github** repo **without the need** to *manually* **change the links and review the files** being pushed. In a way that: every time I "deploy" this code in my `main` **private** branch the code is "merged" in to my **public github** repo.

### What I believe is the answer

I believe that **git filter** while setting a second `remote` in to my **private gitlab** `main` branch *might be the solution*.